# Should System.loadLibrary( name ) find a library already loaded dynamically?

Tags: java, loadlibrary

Can't find the answer to this anywhere.  In Java, does `System.loadLibrary(name)` look for already loaded libraries, including those loaded dynamically? I have a library my app has loaded dynamically. A library package that I am using, then tries to load it statically and does not seem to find it.

Comment: What is the 'library package' and how is it loading the library that is already loaded by your Java program using `System.loadLibrary`?

Comment: The package is FreeImage which has a java wrapper called FreeImage4j. The wrapper uses loadLibrary to load its own freeImage4j.dll which then loads freeImage.dll. My program puts the freeImage4j.dll into the execution directory and adds the directory to java.library.path.  This does not work for freeImage.dll.  The only way it works is for me to put it into System32, ugh.  I have tried dynamically loading the libraries in my program, but that does not work.